# Remainder of Fermat's little theorem sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fermat-numbers

With ***p*** being a prime number, what is the remainder of
 $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} {k^{p-1}}$$ 
divided by ***p*** ?

I know that Fermat's little theorem states that for a prime number ***p***, and a number ***A*** that is not divisible by ***p***: $${A^{p-1}}≡ 1\mod p $$

So I'm thinking that the remainder would be 1, what am I missing here?

Any guidance, clues or solutions are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the remainder be $-1$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You have to sum $1$, $p-1$ times

Comment: Inves I edited Mike's complete answer just in case you missed that the sum which is $p-1 \equiv -1 (mod p)$, so the remainder you're looking for is $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I'm thinking that the remainder would be 1, what am I missing here?

What you are missing, is the basic rule of $$\underset{p-1 \text{ times}}{\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1+1}}=p-1$$ still working in modular arithmetic. It simply wraps if it gets too big, which this sum isn't.

Comment: thank you, that explains the sum. but how would one solve for the sum p-1 divided by p? would the remainder then be p-1 aswell, since p-1 < p ?

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The logic seems fine, but I don't think your conclusion follows from it.  From what you've shown,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{p-1}\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}1 = p-1 \equiv -1\pmod p$$

I'm pretty sure you don't get $1$ from simplifying that.

Comment: only in the special case of $p=2$

Comment: -1 is an alternative version of $p-1$ in modular arithmetic. We say they are congruent, or in the same modular congruence class as each other. this happens because their difference is a multiple of $p$